# How to get kinvey android cache working

Tags: android, caching, offline, kinvey

I have been trying to use kinvey cache for AppData and LinkedData but request only execute online, when offline I get an "Unable to resolve host 'baas.Kinvey.com" error. I've tried all sort of cache policies, nothing is working.. 
Am using kinvey android sdk 2.10.10, on android 5.0

Comment: Have you tried the Caching-Offline guide in Kinvey documentation http://devcenter.kinvey.com/android/guides/caching-offline?

Comment: Yeah I did. Followed the guide to the last sentence but somehow the cache is still not working. Am testing on galaxy s5 android 5.0

Comment: Hi, Can you provide us with the section of code that is failing so that we can see if there is something wrong? - Pranav, Kinvey